# How to enforce 2 MySQL queries to run in series

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need every day to get a list of all Customers past due and insert them into a new table, then i need to move the dates with one month, so they will be processed next month again.

Currently i am running 2 SQL Queries in series

```
insert into history select * from customers where nextdate<CURDATE()
update customers set nextdate=calculation() where nextdate<CURDATE()
```

But sometimes customers are updated, but not inserted into history.

In think that the update begin to run before mysql finished the select.

I am using Node js, he current method i am using for serialization, is that i am running the `update` in the callback from the `insert`, but probably the insert is called back before the code actually runs.

It doesn't happen every time but i think that making a Stored procedure with both in it can help, anyone had some experience with it?

Comment: Show some minimal, runnable code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is that your SELECT and UPDATE don't wait for each because SELECT does not lock the table. You can force locked reading by using:

```sql
INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM customers WHERE nextdate<CURDATE() FOR UPDATE;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html for more information on Locking Reads.

The second is that you probably also want to learn about [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), which let you issue a batch of queries such that either all of them get committed, or none of them do.

In the case of your code, you want to add the start and end commands for issueing a transaction:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM customers WHERE nextdate<CURDATE() FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE customers SET nextdate=calculation() WHERE nextdate<CURDATE();
COMMIT;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html for all the details on this mechanism, which anything from MySQL to Postgres to SQLite supports.

Comment: Here both are executed, but the insert doesn't wait for the update, do transactions ensure serialization?

Comment: Both INSERT and UPDATE are locking operations, so UPDATE can't kick in before INSERT has finished. That said, as your INSERT depends on a SELECT, it's entirely possible that your SELECT is in fact not getting the data you need, and that's worth investigating.

Comment: the insert is not on the same table then the update, do they lock the whole DB?, The select and update are using exact the same where clause, so unless the records are changing they must have the same rows.

Comment: then you probably want to explicitly lock your table so that select (which is a read and never locks a table) will always run before your update. You can make this a locking read, and I've updated the answer for you with instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use promise provided by nodejs to make them in series or you can use `Async series`

#### Async Series

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
      //run your First SQL Query based on response send success or failure callback
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback) {
     //run your Second SQL Query based on response send success or failure callback
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
]
// your call call back should close connection if needed.
```

or you can go with first option

#### Using Promise

(I will recommend to use this one)

```
var conn = db.config(mysql);

run_query(conn,[ 'insert into history select * from customers where nextdate<CURDATE()' ]).then(function(result){

 console.log(result); // result of 1st query

 return run_query(conn,[ 'update customers set nextdate=calculation() where nextdate<CURDATE()']);

}).then(function(result){

   console.log(result.something); // result of 2nd query 
    conn.end();
}).catch(function(err){
  // will run if any error occur
   console.log('there was an error', err);

});
```

Comment: This will most certainly be slower than just asking the DB Engine to make that SELECT a locking operation, and wrapping the calls in a transaction.